# Androidplot legend overlapping

Tags: android, graph, charts, plot, androidplot

What can I do to fix the legend overlapping in androidplot?

Can I manipulate the legend placement?

Comment: what do you need for a detail? the X-Axis legend is overlapping because the names are too many/long/whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this to enlarge the legend:

```
myPlot.getLegendWidget().setSize(new SizeMetrics(15, SizeLayoutType.ABSOLUTE, 200, SizeLayoutType.ABSOLUTE));
```

15 is the height and 200 the width. 

 Change the legend position:

```
myPlot.position(
        myPlot.getLegendWidget(),
            0,
            XLayoutStyle.ABSOLUTE_FROM_RIGHT,
            0,
            YLayoutStyle.ABSOLUTE_FROM_BOTTOM,
            AnchorPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM);
```

And reposition the domain label if you need to:

```
myPlot.position(myPlot.getDomainLabelWidget(),                     
            0,                                    
            XLayoutStyle.ABSOLUTE_FROM_LEFT,       
            15,                                     
            YLayoutStyle.ABSOLUTE_FROM_BOTTOM,     
            AnchorPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM);
```

Comment: SizeMetrics is not available in android plot any more. I got this using "new Size(.. "  instead of SizeMetrics.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the methods used in the above answer did not work for me. I guess things have changed in 4 years. Following code worked for me.

```
    dynamicPlot.getLegendWidget().setSize(new Size(25, SizeLayoutType.ABSOLUTE, 400, SizeLayoutType.ABSOLUTE));

    dynamicPlot.getLegendWidget().position(0,
            XLayoutStyle.ABSOLUTE_FROM_RIGHT,
            0,
            YLayoutStyle.ABSOLUTE_FROM_BOTTOM,
            AnchorPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM);

    dynamicPlot.getDomainLabelWidget().position(0,
            XLayoutStyle.ABSOLUTE_FROM_LEFT,
            30,
            YLayoutStyle.ABSOLUTE_FROM_BOTTOM,
            AnchorPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM);`
```

change the layoutStyle and offsets as per your needs.