# AndroidPlot How to adjust spacing between legend items

Tags: legend, spacing, androidplot

Is there a way to adjust the spacing between particular items of the legend?

Right now, the space is equally distributed among the items, which looks quite ugly with a mixture of very short and very long labels. What I want is to have a constant amount of space between a label and the following icon. How can I achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10600178/androidplot-legend-overlapping

Comment: Thank you for the hint! Still, I guess this is not what I want. It shows me how to enlarge the legend as a whole, but not how to set the size for legend items. Let's say, the legend has a width of 200 and contains 4 items. Then there's 50 pixels for each item. I'm looking for a way to distribute the given space according to item label lenghts, either manually (e.g. 30|60|40|70) or automatically (e.g. keep the same amount of spacing between the last character of an item label and the following item's icon). Am I missing something in the link you provided?